# How to Bind the Multiple Marker in dynamic using jquery in google maps

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I need to bind the "Multiple marker" in Google map, based on the given latitude and longitude and also bind the the marker info window.

I have [Refereed this Link](http://pastebin.com/fQ2Xt8Sq)

And I have tried this code:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.Latitude, this.Longtitude);

                            var contentString = '<span style="color:green;font-size:10pt;">Hospital Name:' + this.hospitalName + '</span><br />Address:<br />' + this.cityName + this.stateName + '<br/><br/>';
                            //this.hospitalName + '</br>' + this.cityName + '</br>' + this.stateName;
                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatLng,
                                map: map,
                                icon: image,
                                shape: shape
                            });
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                infowindow.open(map, this);
                            });
```

Comment: have you tried `looping`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function() {

         var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.Latitude, this.Longtitude);
         var contentString = '<span style="color:green;font-size:10pt;">Hospital Name:'     +   this.hospitalName + '</span><br />Address:<br />' + this.cityName + this.stateName + '<br/><br/>';
      this.hospitalName + '</br>' + this.cityName + '</br>' + this.stateName;
                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatLng,
                                map: map,
                                icon: image,
                                shape: shape
                            });
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                infowindow.open(map, this);
                            });


});
```